# Scraping Data from a website using Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to **scrape** data from cricinfo website and have written a method which accepts a player name and display their corresponding data.

If you see this method takes a player name and display all his data.

My requirement is to display the complete scorecard for all the players instead of displaying the data just for one player.

### URL

https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8039/scorecard/1144490/india-vs-south-africa-8th-match-icc-cricket-world-cup-2019

### Method

```
public static void displayData(WebDriver driver, String input)
{
    WebElement player = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'"+input+"')]"));
    String player_name = player.getText();
    
    WebElement bowled_by = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'"+input+"')]//parent::div//following-sibling::div[@class='cell commentary']"));
    String bowled_by_detail = bowled_by.getText();
    
    List<WebElement> score_card = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'"+input+"')]//parent::div//following-sibling::div[@class='cell runs']"));
    
    System.out.println(player_name);
    System.out.println(bowled_by_detail);
    
    for(int i=0;i<score_card.size();i++)
    {
        String values = score_card.get(i).getText();
        
        System.out.print(values + " | ");
    }System.out.println();
}
```

### Method Execution

displayData(driver, "HM Amla");

### Result

HM Amla
c Sharma b Bumrah
6 | 9 | 16 | 1 | 0 | 66.66 |

Answer (score 0):

Just like BeautifulSoup in python you could use **Jsoup** for web scraping with java, it is pretty fast and you can retrieve the data using css selectors as per your requirement.

We need to traverse to the element block using selenium which has the data and then pass the outerhtml to jsoup to do further scraping of data.